# "Her father left her at her two years for the time till I write it."

Tags: sentence-construction

> Her father left her at her two years for the time till I write it.

Is it correct? or what about

> Her father left her in her childhood till I write it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly, I would use something like:

> "Her father has left her, since she was two years old"

or possibly (if correct):

> "Her father has left her since her second birthday"

By using 'has' there is no need to use the "till I write this" bit.